# In numpy, how can I assign an array of size N to a larger array with a boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy

I want to assign a matrix N values long to N entries in a column of a much longer matrix, where a a boolean mask selects N entries. I am doing it wrong, because the large matrix remains unchanged. Please, see the next example:

Each entry in a large matrix contains a timestamp, a valid flag and an empty field to be filled with the time since the previous valid entry. I want to compute these time lapses:

```
a = np.array([(0,0,0),
       (1,0,0),
       (2,1,0),
       (3,1,0),
       (4,1,0),
       (5,0,0),
       (6,0,0),
       (7,0,0),
       (8,1,0),
       (9,1,0)], 
       dtype=np.dtype([('time', '<i4'), ('ena', '|b1'), ('elapsed', '<i4')]))
```

To calculate time difference with previous unmasked entries:

```
elapsed =  a[a['ena']]['timestamp'][1:] - a[a['ena']]['timestamp'][0:-1]
```

elapsed will be [1,1,4,1], (which is what I wanted).
Now I want to write elapsed seconds to the original array:

```
a[a['ena']]['step_secs'][1:] = timestep
```

there is no warning or error, but a remains unchanged, although I expected:

```
a = np.array([
       (0,0,0),
       (1,0,0),
       (2,1,0),
       (3,1,1),
       (4,1,1),
       (5,0,0),
       (6,0,0),
       (7,0,0),
       (8,1,4),
       (9,1,1)]
```

How should I do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy folks have done some amazing magic to make fancy indexing (which includes boolean indexing) work as well as it does. This magic is pretty impressive but, it still cannot handle fancy indexing followed by more indexing on the left side of the assignment, for example `a[fancy][index2] = something`. Here is a simple example:

```
>>> a = np.zeros(3)
>>> b = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> a[b][1:] = 2
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> a[1:][b[1:]] = 2
array([ 0.,  0.,  2.])
```

I think this is a bug, and I wonder if it is possible to catch it and raise an error instead of letting it silently fail. But getting back to your question, the easiest solution seems to be to replace:

```
a[a['ena']]['step_secs'][1:] = timestep
```

with:

```
tmp = a['ena'][1:]
a['step_secs'][1:][tmp] = timestep
```

or maybe:

```
a['step_secs'][1:][a['ena'][1:]] = timestep
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. What I did in the end to avoid slicing the mask and leaving smart indexing at the end was:  

<code>stepsecs = np.concatenate(([0], stepsecs))<br>  
a['step_secs']['ena'] = stepsecs</code><br>
  
This did the trick.

I think I will report this as a numpy bug: smart indexing should really not fail silently -- it should either work as (I) expected or throw an exception.

Comment: Sorry for the awful formatting in the reply above -- I could not figure out how to make it visually acceptable in the 5' allowed for editing.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible to fix without a change at the python level or a lot of changes to how numpy works. Someone has already submitted a ticket about this. http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/224